# SqlDateTime overflow using NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sqldatetime

I persist my objects using NHibernate in the database

the `App` object have a property defined:

```
public virtual DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

in the mappingClass:

```
Map(x => x.ReleaseDate).Not.Nullable();
```

which in the sqlServer 2008 its dataType is `dateTime` and is not nullable.

for the first Time it saves to database with no error. but after updating app info I encounter `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

but the app release date is a valid dateTime : `2/16/2014 2:21:58 AM` and it's not null.

so Im confused why this exception raise?

```
ist<App> apps = session.QueryOver<Data.Model.App>()
            .List()
            .ToList();
.
.
.
.
for (int i = 0; i < apps.Count(); i++)
        {
            App appWithOldInfo = apps[i];

                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //updating app info
                        appWithOldInfo = UpdateAppInfo(appWithOldInfo, appWithNewInfo);

                        session.Update(appWithOldInfo);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

see the screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's the *only* date and time in your database table? Perhaps there's another one that you've forgotten about, which is defaulting to 1/1/0001?

Comment: yeah I'm sure. see updated post

Comment: I have another field of type `timeStamp` for tracking version changing of entity.

Comment: And what's the value of that?

Comment: value is exactly: `<Binary data>` I can't see the binary data

Comment: Well how are you setting it? Have you tried to reproduce this with a simpler table and a short but complete example you could post?

Comment: The answer here could be in a **different instance** having the default `DateTime` - beeing loaded by *Session*. The suspected to me could be `appWithNewInfo`. If this (other instance) is just loaded from DB, i.e. kept in a Session, during the `session.Flush()` - even this instance is persisted.

Comment: I get appWithNewInfo is an app object which I create using JSON data I get from apple serever. then I update appWithOldInfo with info in appWithNewInfo. even I delete updating app method. I think appWithOldInfo has detached from session. I added some code.

Comment: Is an appWithOldInfo already loaded in this session that has the same primarykey as the one you are trying to update?  If so, you will see the model you expect in the debugger but the session will actually be trying to do stuff with the previously loaded model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks guys for your helpful comments.

The problem wast That I was fetching `device` object from DB which has a property `LastActivityDate`

`List<Device> devices = session.QueryOver<Data.Model.Device>().List().ToList();`

I had added this property to model after addding a device object with some info to the DB.
this property was null, but I haden't defined LastActivityDate as a nullable property.

so this object was in the same session of app object. when I flushed the session, because `LastActivityDate` was null, SqlDateTime exception rised!

it's simple. but I spend hours to find it!!

Comment: So the issue is that another object is being added to the NHibernate session. On the flush (or in my case the commit) NHibernate throws up on itself if all the objects in session dont have all of the right data. To prevent this add a .readonly() extension to the Query<> or QueryOver<> that way NHibernate doesnt track it. In Hashems example he could have done a `List<Device> devices = session.QueryOver<Data.Model.Device>().Readonly().List().ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem, here are the steps to resolve it:

- If you are saving an instance of class A, it doesn't necessarily mean the issue lies within that class alone. Hibernate manages the session, which includes all entities used within that session. It's possible that one of the entities is causing the issue. Essentially, this error indicates that you are trying to pass a null value into a not-null date field.

Comment: You are not wrong, you are just 10 years late... The author himself gave the same solution 10 years ago!